# Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration : How to use Spring Framework's @initBinder with Jersey framework

Tags: java, spring, security, filter, jersey-2.0

I want to avoid Mass Assignment: Insecure Binder Configuration issue for our application which is written in Jersey framework. I was thinking is there any other way we can use @InitBinder from spring and for each request to this service only allow to set the allowed properties and set all other properties to null.

```
@Controller
@Path("/ar")
@Api(tags = { "Request" })
public class RequestService extends AbstractService {
    static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger("RequestServiceLogger");

@InitBinder
    public void customizeBinding (WebDataBinder binder) {
        System.out.println("Inside init binder ============== ");
        //I want to allow the allowed field only for AccountRequest object
         binder.setAllowedFields(allowedFields);
    }

    @Path("/submitrequest")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Validates a request", notes = "Validates a request", response = RequestResponse.class)
    @ApiImplicitParams({ @io.swagger.annotations.ApiImplicitParam(name = "Auth", value = "value", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })
    @ApiResponses({
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", responseHeaders = { @io.swagger.annotations.ResponseHeader(name = "X-ResponseTime", description = "Total Time Taken", response = String.class) }, response = RequestResponse.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Method Not Allowed", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 415, message = "Unsupported Media Type", response = com.model.ErrorDetail.class),
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server error", response = com.ErrorDetail.class) })
    public Response submitRequest(@ApiParam(value = "AccountRequest JSON input data.", required = true) AccountRequest accountRequest,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Inside submitRequest ============== ");
    }
}
```

*** If there are any other alternative ways to filter request object properties please let me know.

Comment: That won't work, you cannot use the spring binding mechanism (or configuration for that matter) with Jersey. You will have to configure Jersey appropriately.

Comment: @M. Deinum is there any other way to do it using Jersey framework.